# How to get the closest value of date from table? Input parameter is 2012-02-10

Tags: mysql, sql, select, where-clause

```
+------------+
| date       |
+------------+
| 2011-10-26 |
| 2011-11-01 |
| 2011-11-10 |
| 2011-11-24 |
| 2011-11-28 |
| 2011-12-05 |
| 2011-12-07 |
| 2011-12-19 |
| 2011-12-23 |
| 2011-12-28 |
| 2012-01-04 |
| 2012-01-10 |
| 2012-01-14 |
| 2012-01-20 |
| 2012-01-25 |
| 2012-02-02 |
| 2012-02-06 |
| 2012-02-21 |
| 2012-02-27 |
| 2012-03-01 |
+------------+
```

I have no any idea of how to do it. Please help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the closest value to a given date, sort by the absolute value of the difference:

```
select *
from t
order by abs(datediff(date, date('2012-02-10')))
limit 1
```

Comment: It's working with some strangeness e.g.'2012-02-04' is giving '2012-02-02' instead of '2012-02-06'. What is the cause of that behaviour?

Comment: @ILMIR . . . Both are two days away from the date.  One is arbitrarily picked.

Comment: It suits me, anyway :) Thanks a lot!